# Redirect a URL ending .pl

Tags: .htaccess, cgi

There are several links on third party websites to a URL on my website:
http://example.com/cgi-bin/sp000000.pl

That script is no longer present.

Is there a way to redirct that URL to another using .htaccess or a .pl script?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 \.pl$ http://example.com/
```